# Sony XM4 Disable Mich to Get Better Audio?

Tags: arch-linux, bluetooth, bluez

So I have the Sony XM4 and sometimes I see the headset bluetooth instead of the others which give me better quality

```
261     bluez_output.14_3F_A6_83_08_17.headset-head-unit        PipeWire        s16le 1ch 16000Hz       SUSPENDED
```

When I see this the audio quality is crap. What can I do to get better quality? I think this is because this version has the mic which lowers the quality

When it connect right I see it as

```
bluez_output.14_3F_A6_83_08_17.a2dp-sink
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, one has to sacrifice audio quality to enable the mic in Linux for these headsets.

The A2DP codecs are all output only. If you need your microphone you need to switch the profile to mSBC. That's the case everywhere and for everyone.

That's a limitation of the bluetooth protocol.

Exception to that are mobile phones, but that's because they use proprietary codecs that no free implementation exists for.